# Where can I read interesting articles about science in Esperanto?

Tags: resources

I'm looking for a website or magazine that has interesting, well-written and scientific articles.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's ISAE that is issuing [Scienca Revuo](https://scienca-revuo.info/) every now and then. On their website there's a huge archive of scientific articles that date back until 1949. Unfortunately due to lack of contributions recently not that many issues could be issued. Therefore there's now a [blogish website](https://aktuale.scienca-revuo.info/) for more casual stuff on science.

Another interesting resource is http://teleskopo.com/

Answer (score 1):

Following the [scientific congress KAEST](https://kaest2018.ikso.net/programo/prelegoj/), there is usually a congress book printed based on the lectures during the congress. I think they're available through Libro Servo, but I'm not sure.

There is also another blog about scientific topics that hasn't been mentioned yet: [Scivolemo](https://scivolemo.wordpress.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I have written [16 articles in Esperanto](http://web.archive.org/web/20170830115134/http://www.public-domain-materials.com/dosierujo-artikoloj-en-esperanto.html), 3 of which I would count as addressing your request:

- La Lingvo-Bariero kiel Beletra Rimedo
- Miraklo de Morley
- Formulo por la Leĝo de Engel

The articles are available at: http://web.archive.org/web/20170830115134/http://www.public-domain-materials.com/dosierujo-artikoloj-en-esperanto.html

Comment: While the list of the articles has been archived, none of the articles themselves except for [Miraklo de Morley](https://web.archive.org/web/20170830115134/http://www.public-domain-materials.com/uploads/1/1/6/2/11622700/morleys_miracle.pdf) seem to have been archived.